# XSLT - Change attribute and apply dynamic id same time

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have xml file like follows,

```
<doc>
  <a ref="Foot"></a>
  <a ref="Foot"></a>
  <a ref="Foot"></a>
  <a ref="End"></a>
  <a ref="End"></a>
  <a ref="End"></a>
  <a ref="Head"></a>
  <a ref="Head"></a>
<doc>
```

my requirement was add dynamically increment id attribute to the `<a>` node that have `"End"` attribute. and also change `"Foot"` attribute with `"End"` so the result document would be,

```
<doc>
  <a ref="End" id="1"></a>
  <a ref="End" id="2"></a>
  <a ref="End" id="3"></a>
  <a ref="End" id="4"></a>
  <a ref="End" id="5"></a>
  <a ref="End" id="6"></a>
  <a ref="Head"></a>
  <a ref="Head"></a>
<doc>
```

I was able to add dynamic id to nodes and change the `"Foot"` attribute with `"End"` but the id's only added to the node which previously have `"End"` attribute. nodes which have attribute `"Foot"` do not add the id. My current output is follows,

```
<doc>
  <a ref="End"></a>
  <a ref="End"></a>
  <a ref="End"></a>
  <a ref="End" id="1"></a>
  <a ref="End" id="2"></a>
  <a ref="End" id="3"></a>
  <a ref="Head"></a>
  <a ref="Head"></a>
<doc>
```

My xsl code is follows,

```
 //change attribute "Foot" to attribute "End" 
 <xsl:template match="a/@ref[. = 'Foot']">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">End</xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>


//adds dynamic id's to foot node
<xsl:template match="a/@ref[.='End']">
   <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:number count="a[@ref='End']" level="any"></xsl:number>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is how can add id's to first three nodes which previously had attribute `"Foot"`. 
It is possible that apply template to `<a>` (`<xsl:template match="a">`)node and increment id but that will not do the job because if I did that `<a>` which have attribute "Head" are also apply the ids.

I thinks I may could use xls variable and increment value or something but I have less experience in xslt and I cannot think of a proper way how should I do it

can anyone suggest me an answer how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[@ref='Foot' or @ref='End']">
    <a ref="End">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:number count="a[@ref='Foot' or @ref='End']"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```